# Adonis V4 - How to delete with relationship

Tags: relationship, adonis.js

Soo I have a `Delivery` Model and has a `hasMany` relationship with `SelectedDriver` Model
and the `SelectedDriver` Model also have a `hasMany` relationship with Invoice Model and other models.

```js
class Delivery extends Model {
  selected_driver() {
    return this.hasMany('App/Models/SelectedDriver')
  }
}
```

```js
class SelectedDriver extends Model {
  user() {
    return this.belongsTo('App/Models/User')
  }

  delivery_orders() {
    return this.hasMany('App/Models/DeliveryOrder')
  }

  stocks() {
    return this.hasMany('App/Models/Stock')
  }

  estimated_revenue() {
    return this.hasOne('App/Models/EstimatedRevenue')
  }

  invoices() {
    return this.hasMany('App/Models/Invoice')
  }
}
```

so what I want to ask is what is the best and easiest way to delete all of them when I delete A Delivery??
When I delete a Delivery, the Selected Drivers and Invoices should be deleted as well.
Thanks in Advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `onDelete('CASCADE')` in your migrations. For instance:

```
this.alter('selected_drivers', table => {
  table
    .integer('delivery_id')
    .unsigned()
    .references('id')
    .inTable('deliveries')
    .onDelete('CASCADE')
})
```

This is, when a delivery is deleted, the selected_drivers related will be delete too. For more infos, read the knex doc http://knexjs.org/#Schema-onDelete